# struts reset() is not called before populating the form

Tags: struts

I got a strange (and probably) wrong behaviour here. I was trying to put a checkbox on the page, and you know it: unchecked checkboxes are not written to the request (only checked boxes are)

What struts normally offers is to override:

```
@Override
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, ServletRequest request)
```

to reset all the checkboxes to "false".
But in my case, this reset() is never called!

Someone got an idea?

Thanks in advance,

mana

Comment: May be, it is because the request url is looking for jsp, not the mapping for struts-action(e.g. *.do). Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reset method is automatically called by the Struts framework (your observation on The Elite Gentleman's answer is correct)... that is if you did everything by the book.

Check the following:

1. are you extending an ActionForm
   class or something else?
2. did you by any chance overwrite the
   reset method in a subclass of the
   one you are not getting the method called and you
   use that for your action?
3. are you managing the form life cycle
   by hand, instead of letting Struts
   do it?
4. in struts-config, did you specify
   that your action uses that
   particular form by specifying the
   `name` attribute on the `action` tag?

My money is on number 4.

Comment: Well, I checked:
1. My Form is extending ValidationActionForm, which is extending Action Form. 
2. In the debugger, it says the correct instance of my Form. In case any subclass would override reset(), too - this will not be a problem, since the reset() of the upper most class will be called. From there I call super.reset().
3. The Form is only described in the struts-config.xml (I don't do new MyForm(); and session.add(myForm) or such stuff)
4. Yes, the action has the correct name of the Form (with session scope)

Comment: Strange... Maybe if you provide some more code with your question. Also,do you have an attribute named "attribute" on the action tag in struts-config? Do you use <html:form> tags in the JSP to retrieve the form or you use something else (like a plain vanilla form)?

Answer (score 4):

The correct method signature to override is

> public void reset(ActionMapping
>   mapping,
>                     **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest**
>   request)

Comment: (Possibly depending on your version of Struts) This is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

The solution was to add attribute **scope="request"** in the action tag in struts-config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Reset is never called by default, you have to call it through your actions (if you want to reset your form),

alternatively, on your jsp, you'll have `<html:reset />` tag and override the reset method of `ActionForm`. this helps.

Comment: I dont want to reset the whole form. I just want to set all the fields which hold values from the checkboxes to "false" - so that checked boxes are correctly written to these fiels with the value "true" ... and unchecked boxes (whose value is not transmitted in the request) stick at "false". This normally is an automatism within struts, but as I said, that reset() is not executed in my case.

Comment: in that case, on your action, override the `reset()` method and then on your method e.g.
<br /> `public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { form.reset(); return mapping.findForward(..);}`....What I mean is that you can (typecast) call the `reset()` as I did in the example.

Comment: the reset() normally doesn't need to be called manually. It has to be called by the struts framework? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @mana: you are correct, in normal operating coditions Struts calls reset automatically.

Answer (score 0):

prototype of `reset()` method is:

```
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
```

If we are not using `reset()` method when that time we are trying to open our application then previous values will be coming automatically.
If we are using this `reset()` method the previous values will be reset into empty values. So by using this `reset()` method we can avoid previous values.